# Using findViewById in a Non-Activity Class

Tags: java, android, button, media, android-context

I'm trying to use `findViewById` `getApplicationContext` and `getSystemService` within the `MediaButtonReceiver` class but none of the methods can be resolved. I assume I need to pass context to the `MediaButtonReceiver` class in order to allow for the use of these functions but I can't figure out how

Class trying to use the methods:

```
public class external extends MediaButtonReceiver {

private Context context;

Activity activity;
public external(Context context,Activity activity){
    this.context=context;
    this.activity=activity;
}



@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("Button", "pressed");




    final ToggleButton toggleWF = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.WiFi_toggle);
    final ToggleButton toggleBT = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.BT_toggle);
    final ToggleButton toggleNFC = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.NFC_toggle);
    NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ((AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE)).registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(new ComponentName(
            this,
            external.class));


    external External = new external(MainActivity.this,this);

}

}
```

Comment: Please explain what you need to achieve, as far as I can understand, you are trying to fire BroadcastReceiver right?and from broadcast receiver you need to show UI to get user input? In that case the way you are triggering broadcast receiver is wrong. Please comment on the question, then I can give you answer code.

Comment: You don't need a Context and Activity.. Any Activity is already a Context

Comment: @ChethanShetty essentially I'm trying to make it so that when an external media button is pressed the app will check the status of toggle buttons and then utilize those states/variables in the code afterwards. The external button code works, I just need to make it so that the methods methods listed above are usable in the MediaButtonReceiver class or I could put these methods in the MainActivity if I could find a way to make the variables accessible in the MediaButtonReceiver class. I just don't know how to go about either of these solutions.

Comment: @JamesDooney BroadcastReceivers are meant only to be fired for a specific event we register it for. If we need to perform with respect to UI, it should be done through Activity. As far as I can understand from your comment, you need toggle button states right? Why don't you use `SharedPreference` and save the state as boolean when toggle button state is changed. Then in your receiver read values from `SharedPreference`

Answer (score 0):

you can use layout like this.

```
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_xml);


        // set the dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do long running operation in Receiver and you can open dialog activity or activity from onReceive method like context.startActivity(new Intent(contex,Activity.class) and in Activity class you can perform whatever you want. Also don't pass activity object to Receiver using constructor